# VBA Subscript out of range - error 9 Fault

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me with this code, I am getting a subscript out of range error:

[image]

```vb
Dim ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 As Long
Dim ultimafilaauxiliarZB2 As Long
Dim ultimafilaauxiliarZN1 As Long
Dim ultimafilaauxiliarZN2 As Long

Dim cont As Integer

     If (Range("D23").Value > 49) Then

        ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   ## HERE ERROR ##
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 + 1, 12) = Range("D23").Value
        Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 + 1, 13) = Range("C23").Value
        
     End If
```

Comment: This can be anything. Does the "Hoja1" sheet exist? does it have an L column? You should break that line to it's method calls and see where exactly the error comes from.

Comment: Actually that cannot be anything. If the error occurs in the marked line the only thing that can throw this kind of error is: Sheet `Hoja1` does not exist (at least not in the workbook your code is looking for it).

Comment: It could be that Sheets("Hoja1") does exist but has fewer rows than the ActiveSheet. Takeaway is that `Rows.Count` will be executed on the ActiveSheet if, as is the case in your code, no sheet for the count is specified.

Comment: @Variatus while you are correct that this *could* be an issue, there is (as far as I know) no possibility that different sheets in the same workbook have different amounts of rows. In one workbook all worksheets have the same `Rows.Count`. Since no workbook was specified all references should go to the same workbook. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @PEH Perfectly reasoned. Point conceded  :-)

Comment: @Ferdi make sure you are in the correct workbook if you are working with multiple workbooks at the same time you need to specify in which workbook the `Sheets("Hoja1")` is.

Comment: If you are in a chart-sheet when `Rows.Count` is called, I can see how that could create problems. @Pᴇʜ

Comment: @eirikdaude while that is correct and *could* be an issue, it would produce *"Runtime Error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error"* and not *"Runtime Error 9 Subscript out of range"*.

Comment: True. I was just mentioning it for completeness sake. I agree with you first comment here for what the reason is likely to be. @Pᴇʜ

Comment: The problem may be that I have 2 sheets connected and the reference to the value is: = '[DASHBOARD_FINAL0000.xlsx] Board'! $ Q $ 2 When I change the value in the sheet "DASHBOARD_FINAL0000" the sheet where I have the Macro gives the error .

Comment: As I said you need to specify in which workbook `Sheets("Hoja1")` is: Like `Workbooks("DASHBOARD_FINAL0000.xlsx").Sheets("Hoja1")` or  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")`. Note `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is written in while `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus (is on top). • Also you need to specify a workbook and worksheet for **all** `Range` objects.

Comment: ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    .                              Excellent thank you very much . This solved the problem.

Comment: Excuse me, I wanted to place it myself but I don't know what I did. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in which workbook `Sheets("Hoja1")` is, like:

```
Workbooks("DASHBOARD_FINAL0000.xlsx").Sheets("Hoja1")
```

or

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")
```

Note that `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is written in while `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus (is on top).

Also you need to specify a workbook and worksheet for **all** your `Range`  objects.

```
 Dim wsHoja1 As Worksheet 'define your worksheet
 Set wsHoja1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")

 If (ActiveSheet.Range("D23").Value > 49) Then
    ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 = wsHoja1.Range("L" & wsHoja1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    wsHoja1.Cells(ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 + 1, 12) = ActiveSheet.Range("D23").Value
    wsHoja1.Cells(ultimafilaauxiliarZB1 + 1, 13) = ActiveSheet.Range("C23").Value
 End If
```